# Centering Text in a JTextArea or JTextPane - Horizontal Text Alignment

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtextpane

Is there a way to create horizontally centered text for a JTextArea like with a JTextField?

```
setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
```

Is there a way I can accomplish the same thing with a multi-line text area? I can't find a method for it with JTextArea, so is there another option? JTextPane? If so, how?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to use a JTextPane and use attributes. The following should center all the text:

```
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
```

Edit:

Vertical centering is not supported as far as I know. Here is some code you might find useful: [Vertical Alignment of JTextPane](http://java-sl.com/tip_center_vertically.html)

Comment: What about if I wanted to also have it vertically centered as well?

Comment: There are no casting problems with the code above. Note that if you are using a JEditorPane, only StyledDocument supports the setParagraphAttributes() method. You will need to cast the result of getDocument() to StyledDocument.

Comment: Not sure how this code above works but I needed to make doc.setParagraphAttributes(center, false) to make it work.