# How do I align selected text in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextpane

relatively self-explaining, How can i center selected text in a JTextPane?

(Aligning Any text is helpful)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering Text in a JTextArea or JTextPane - Horizontal Text Alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213045/centering-text-in-a-jtextarea-or-jtextpane-horizontal-text-alignment)

Answer (score 3):

Found some code on coderanch:

```
     SimpleAttributeSet attribs = new SimpleAttributeSet();  
StyleConstants.setAlignment(attribs , StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);  
pane.setParagraphAttributes(attribs,true);
```