# JButton ignore indicated size

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm a new in Swing. I'm trying to create a window 800x600 that will be divided into two equal parts (800x300): first one a immutable text-area and the second - button.

***Problem:*** Button should occupy the bottom half of the window. But seems button size doesn't work correct.

***Code:***

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lingvo frame");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4,4,4));
        final JButton showResultButton = new JButton();
        showResultButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 300));
        showResultButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        showResultButton.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(showResultButton);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        showResultButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                showResultButton.setText("translation");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your frame to a `GridLayout`. Also note just set the size of `JTextArea` using this constructor `JtextArea(rows, columns)` and just `pack()` your frame. No need to set size to anything. The`GridLayout` will handle the size of the `JButton` for you, based on the size of the `JTextArea`

Also Swing apps should be run from the Event Dispatch Thread. See [**Initial Threads**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Also see [**Laying out Components within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to learn more about layout managers.

Here's a running example

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lingvo frame");

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                final JButton showResultButton = new JButton();
                final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 60);

                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                frame.add(textArea);
                frame.add(showResultButton);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                showResultButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        showResultButton.setText("translation");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you align your alignt JTextArea text to center please? And set some beautiful font to it?

Comment: What do you mean align to the center? Also see [**How to Use Fonts**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html). Once you learn that, just use `textArea.setFont(font)`

Comment: I mean that if I set text to JTextArea it'll be shown at the left top corner of the text area

Comment: So you _don't_ want it aligned in the top-left?

Comment: I want it'll be aligned at the center (both horizontal and vertical)

Comment: Ok that is a whole other SO question you should be asking. But you can take a look that [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3213361/2587435) and [**this**](http://java-sl.com/tip_center_vertically.html)

Answer (score 1):

The panel where the button is inserted has a `GridLayout(4,4,4,4)`. This means that the Panel will contain 4*4 components, and all will have the same size (!).

Your code does not contain a text area at the moment. But based on the description, your layout could probably be achieved with

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
panel.add(theTextArea); // The top half
panel.add(button); // The bottom half
```

You'll have to read a little about Layout Managers ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html ) to become familiar with them. Particularly concerning the question of how they take the "preferred size" into account.