# Center text in TextArea

Tags: java, awt, textarea, text-alignment

Is there a way to horizontally align a text in a textarea from awt? There is a getAlignment method but not a setAlignment. And I just want to use awt, not swing

Comment: You have to upload some code. We can't help you like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213045/centering-text-in-a-jtextarea-or-jtextpane-horizontal-text-alignment

Comment: *"And I just want to use awt, not swing"*  ..Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no alignment property for a TextArea.  The alignment is determined by which LayoutManager you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You should try putting your components(eg TextArea) into containers it makes laying them out a much less stressfull task.

Take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

GridLayout or BorderLayout may be ones you should take a look at in particular. Best of luck!