# Setting JTable column Horizontal Alignment without using DefaultTableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have the following `TableCellRenderer` (NOT `DefaultTableCellRenderer`) which allows me to skip lines in my `JTable`'s cells:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class MyCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {

  Color highlightBackground = (Color) UIManager.get("Table.selectionBackground");

  public MyCellRenderer() {
    setLineWrap(true);
    setWrapStyleWord(true);
  }

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    setText((String) value); //or something in value, like value.getNote()...
    setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(), getPreferredSize().height);
    if (table.getRowHeight(row) != getPreferredSize().height) {
      table.setRowHeight(row, getPreferredSize().height);
    }
    if (table.isRowSelected(row)) {
      this.setBackground(highlightBackground);
    } else {
      this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
```

I would just like to change the horizontal alignment of this renderer. (Meaning the cells would have the text in their center or right, right now it's left).

Here's how I use this TableCellRenderer :

```
Table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by horizontal alignment of renderer? Do you mean alignment of cells?

Comment: There's no need to call `setSize`, the `JTable` will do that itself.  Change alignment to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Have found the answer, thanks TT. for the hints, I simply removed the custom constructor and its linewrap, extended JTextPane, and added a few lines of code.
For anyone who needs a class that allows skipping lines & setting horizontal alignment of cells, here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class MyCellRenderer extends JTextPane implements TableCellRenderer {

Color highlightBackground = (Color) UIManager.get("Table.selectionBackground");

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    setText((String) value);//or something in value, like value.getNote()...
    setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),
            getPreferredSize().height);
    if (table.getRowHeight(row) != getPreferredSize().height) {
        table.setRowHeight(row, getPreferredSize().height);
    }
    if (table.isRowSelected(row)) {
        this.setBackground(highlightBackground);
    } else {
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    //Added lines
    StyledDocument doc = this.getStyledDocument();
    SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
    doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
    //Added Lines

    return this;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with JTextArea.

Your cell renderer should be extending JTextPane instead, so you could call from your `getTableCellRendererComponent` implementation or the constructor of the renderer:

```
StyledDocument doc = getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
```

If you wanted to center. Shamelessly plugged from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3213361/243373) on StackOverflow.

Comment: This will only work for a JTextPane, not a JTextArea.

Comment: @camickr Hmz good point =) so back to setAlignmentY I suppose

Comment: @camickr You got EXP in things like these looking at your user profile... Do you think JTextArea would be a good component to extend from, or would he be better off extending JTextPane?

Comment: Not sure I really understand what the OP is trying to do so I don't have a suggestion.

Comment: setAlignmentY does not work (neither does setAlignmentX)

Comment: Have you considered using another control, like JTextPane? I think JTextArea is just too primitive to allow for setting alignment. Try it out. If you think you can use JTextPane rather than JTextArea, I will revert my answer to the previous (which has a solution to set alignment for it).

Comment: Look at [this thread on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3213045/243373) which also suggests that it is not possible with a JTextArea. Consider moving to JTextPane. It is a little more involved than JTextArea but at least you can set alignment on it.

Comment: You are quite welcome. Did you end up using JTextPane then?

Comment: Yes, I've written the solution down.

Comment: @Elio answer rollbacked, and provided some text saying you can't do it with JTextArea. GL!